# Custom Jackson Mapping for Inner Classes

Tags: json, spring-mvc, mapping, jackson

I'm developing an Spring MVC application that uses Jackson for JSON views.
Suppose that I have two classes like following.

```
class A {
   String prop;
   B other;
   // getters setters
}

class B {
   Integer id;
   String name;
}
```

What i'm trying to resolve is to get a JSON string like following.
for a fully initialized instance of A

```
{prop:"something", name:"otherthing"} // in here the class B 
                                      // is replaced with its propery name
```

insted of

```
{prop:"something, other:{id:5,name:"otherthing"}}
```

NOTE: the two classes mentioned above are Entity classes for Hibernate.
I have used @JsonIgnore to eliminate some properties from JSON output, Is it posible to
replace a sub-class with its property using annotation?

Comment: One suggestion: "inner class" might be misleading in the title, since this is not really related to Java inner classes, but rather to inlining of JSON structure. But not sure what would be optimal title to make it easy to find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet possible except by using custom serializer, although there is a feature request ( http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-132 ) that might make it in Jackson 1.9 (as it has relatively high vote count, meaning a few users would really like to see it implemented).

Comment: 1.9 will have @JsonUnwrapped; implemented in trunk, working. So if you really need it, can just build from trunk; or wait until official release is out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use a library other than Jackson for your JSON serialization, then you can use GSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) with a custom GsonBuilder object, which may get you close to what you're trying to acheive.

If you check out this [blog post](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/07/gson-v-jackson-part-4.html) it shows how to customize the GSON serializer in a few different ways. I'm using it with a custom ExclusionStrategy to correctly translate my model objects (which are full of circular references) to JSON for a RESTful webservice using Spring MVC. (Note that I am only using it to serialize, not to deserialize.)

I've got my GsonBuilder's set up inside different View beans, which you can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/pushee/source/browse/trunk/pushee/src/main/java/org/mitre/pushee/hub/model/serializer). If that looks like it might help you out and you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Custom GsonBuilder is pretty much a custom serializer, so not sure if that's easier than with custom handlers of other JSON libs?

Comment: A point of clarification: A GsonBuilder is an object that builds Gson instances.  What Amanda referenced are not examples of a "custom" GsonBuilder -- they are just examples of using a GsonBuilder.  Also, handling circular references isn't very closely related to the problem described in the original question, which is asking about serializing an object reference to just a JSON string, instead of to a JSON object.  Gson does not currently have a feature to make this easier than the possible solutions with Jackson.  Both Gson and Jackson would require custom serialization processing.